# Finding the angle between two segment in r

Tags: r, linear-regression, angle

As mentioned in the title, i need to find the angle between two segment.

Test is a function who i created for my data, it's segmented(linear model) This is just some details to be more specific.

```
Test(14)
Call: segmented.lm(obj = L, seg.Z = ~n)

Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
(Intercept)            n         U1.n  
      97.74       -16.18        25.48  

Estimated Break-Point(s):  

psi1.n  
 1.551 

slope(Test(14))

$n

           Est. St.Err. t value CI(95%).l CI(95%).u
slope1 -16.1840  9.3302 -1.7346  -134.740   102.370
slope2   9.2916  4.6651  1.9917   -49.984    68.568
```

As you can see n is the left slope and U1.n is the difference between slopes (`psi1.n` is the breakpoint)

So I created the following function:

```
angle<-function(x){
  m=Test(x)$coef[2]
  n=Test(x)$coef[3]+m
  return(atan((n - m) / (1 + (m * n))))
}
```

for x=14 it gives me -9.68 degrees after multiplying the output by 180/pi

As shown in this picture below this is not acceptable:

[image]

Comment: @RonakShah pleas could you add also the graphe showing the segments?

Comment: Why *"this is not acceptable"*? Have you seen the scale difference between the axis? x is in (0, 1) and y in (70, 100). That angle is (very) acute.

Comment: Add the argument `asp=1` to your plot command.

Comment: Thanks you for the help!